# On operator norm of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I was going through some lecture notes on operators on Hilbert space and on a proof it is stated

> note that $||T||=\sup_{||x||=||y||=1}\text{Re}\langle Tx,y\rangle$

However I cannot see why this is true. Is this something that holds only for symmetric operators or is it more general? Can someone enlighten me?

The above can be found in [here](http://www.math.washington.edu/~hart/m556/lecture2.pdf), it is in the proof of lemma 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is more general.  By definition, $$\|T\| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \|Tx\|/\|x\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1} \|Tx\|$$
But for any $z$ in the Hilbert space there is $y$ with $\|y \| = 1$ 
such that $\langle z, y \rangle = \|z\|$, while of course for any $y$ with $\|y\|=1$,
$\text{Re} \langle z, y \rangle \le |\langle z, y \rangle| \le \|z\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much Robert, it had puzzled me for a couple of hours.

Comment: Might be helpful to point out that this is a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem.